# Copy files from server to windows mobile

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, .net-cf-3.5

I am creating a windows mobile application in c#. I want to move files from http server to windows mobile. I dont know where and how to start? Can some one tell me ideas and share some links? I am using .net compact framework 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Your windows-mobile consists of a browser application, which is just like a normal browser. You can use it to download files from your http server. For example, goto your windows mobile browser and type:

http://myhttpserver.com/example.zip

assuming example.zip is the file you want to download.

Comment: This is not exactly what I want. I must not do any operations on windows mobile. I can perform operations only on server.

Comment: @Badhri Ravikumar - Is your web-server in the local network of the moble? If that is not the case, I think you will have to create a specialized application on your WP that can track the remote server and fetch your download, and then may be configure your phone/app. I believe you can use Visual Studio 2008/2010 to create such an app. There is no other way, as Windows security model will never permit the remote http-server to inject

Comment: Yes, the web-server is in the local network of the mobile. And I am using Visual Studio 2008. Now what can I do?

Comment: See this link http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-wpdevices/transfer-files-from-pc-to-windows-mobile-7-phone/acfb46b0-5d17-4a09-a0d6-54e3a6ab3246. It seems you will have to either email it to your phone or put the files on a sky drive, you can use any of these suggestions. You can also write a WP7 app in C# that can track the files transferred from the server via wifi/bluetooth, I don't have expertise in that, though. See if you can use the System.Net namespace in WP7. If you can do that, maybe you can do an FTP transfer with your server from the mobile.